# Shadowbox(Image gallery plugin) shows black window only

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, jquery-plugins, shadowbox

I'm trying to create an image gallery using Shadowbox plugin(http://www.shadowbox-js.com).
So  I got a problem with creating the gallery, That problem is: whenever I click on the link(actually thumbnail) that displays the image it starts loading then no image is displayed only a black window.
The links I use:

```
<a href="http://localhost/myProject/images/10.jpg" rel="shadowbox"><img src="http://localhost/myProject/thumbnails/10.jpg" class="thumbnails"/></a>
```

The script/link/init :
These imports are working, I verify it by using(in Chrome) Inspect element->Network.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="shadowbox/shadowbox.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="shadowbox/shadowbox.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
        Shadowbox.init();
</script>
```

**notes:**
1-I'm using Shadowbox as a jQuery plugin(NOT standalone).
2-jQuery is imported to my website using Google(NOT locally).
3-The real image size is 3000x2400.
Edit:
 4- I realized that when right clicking->inspect element(in chrome) , the image is shown(but not in a proper way, only half of it is shown).
 5-when setting `handleOversize` to `drag` the image is shown(Must click).
6-It is working in IE 9!.

Comment: QUESTION SOLVED. waiting for 3 hours to add the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, It wasn't in the DOCTYPE or the browser or even my JS code!
The problem was in the `CSS`.
Setting the `direction` to `right to left(rtl)`(yes, the website is Arabic).
caused the images to be hidden, maybe, because the image went right and I cant see it.

Answer (score 0):

You're saying that the image is not showing properly in the browser?

It may mean that the file is corrupted. Try re-saving it.

I've been using Shadowbox for quite long time now and similar problems were always caused by bad files or the files permissions not been set properly.

Comment: No, the image is not corrupted, as I said `6-It is working in IE 9!.`

Comment: If the image is not showing in other browser than IE it may mean that the file is corrupted and IE can show it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Since your providing an example that is *local host*, I can only offer general guidance and not tell you exactly what the problem is. A link surely would be welcomed.

First, make sure your call to **jQuery** is before the call to `shadowbox.js` file.

Other than that I'm sure you've given the webpage a valid `!DOCTYPE` which makes your Shadowbox markup correct so far as I can see at this point.

The problem could be with using **jQuery** and your Class Name of `thumbnails`.

If **jQuery** has modified the link with a particular style, Shadowbox may be subject to any changes in it's anchor tag.

Those changes then will cause the Shadowbox per link element to not see the original link since it's now a jQuery link. It will need to be re-cached by Shadowbox.

Solution: Try making the call to `Shadowbox.init` after any modifications to the `thumbnail` have been completed so Shadowbox caches the link once, or if needed use Shadowbox API `.clearCache();` and `.setup();` to re-cache those `rel` anchors.

I should also mention that you should ensure Shadowbox has the jQuery Adapter interface which is a download option or WordPress Plugin option.

Comment: I tried putting `Shadowbox.init` at the bottom of the page, same result was given, Also the gallery works when using iE9..

Comment: Remember **Shadowbox.init** can only be called once. Try checking if the class name is causing the issue. Remove it and retest. If no-go then reviewing your full webpage is needed. Perhaps you can [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) that if you have further issues?

Comment: I removed the class , didn't fix the problem, the class is made for the thumbnails so it has nothing to do with the real image.and for rebuilding the page, I don't think that is the right decision, because it is working in IE9 , so it might be the !DOCTYPE, what is the proper !DOCTYPE ?

Comment: If the thumbnail class is affected by jQuery via parent then Shadowbox will inherit those CSS rules. Actually, Shadowbox is affected by any CSS rules applied to the element that interferes with the shadowbox.css file. The reason it's working in IE9 is because different CSS rules are affecting the webpage. The proper DOCTYPE is based on your markup. With over 1000 posts as a self-appointed [Shadowbox member](http://shadowbox.1309102.n2.nabble.com/template/NamlServlet.jtp?macro=user_nodes&user=320743) to help others with their Shadowbox issues, I am sure I can help you once I see your markup.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question but no one answered correctly to this subject.
solution is here:
just replace "left" values with "right" and "right" values with "left" in shadowbox.css

Answer (score -3):

Open the shadowbox.css and set `direction:ltr` for `#sb-containe`r